# construct a counterexample in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Problem:
Construct a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{F}$ of subsets of $R$ such that no open interval is measurable with respect to $\mathscr{F}$, although any singleton $\{x\}$ is ($x\in R$). I tried to construct an example like the complement of any open interval is not in $\mathscr{F}$, but I did not make it. Can someone give a hint?

Comment: Take the smallest sigma algebra generated by the singletons.

Comment: You mean $\cap_{x\in R}\{\mathscr{G}:x\subseteq\mathscr{G},\mathscr{G}\text{ is a }\sigma\text{-algebra over} R\}$

Comment: No, that intersection is $\{\emptyset, R\}$. It should be the intersection of all sigma algebras that contain (each) all singletons. The result of this intersection is the sigma algebra in Mnifldz's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the collection $\mathscr{F}$ where $A \in \mathscr{F}$ if $A$ is either empty, at most countable, or has a complement which is at most countable.  This is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ where no interval is contained in it (unless you consider $\mathbb{R}$ itself which needs to be in there anyway).

Comment: Can you write down your $\mathscr{F}$ as specific form? Then, I can prove it is sigma algebra and it does not contain open interval.

Comment: Do you mean $$\mathscr F\equiv\{E\subseteq\mathbb R\,|\,E\text{ is countable or }E^c\text{ is countable}\}$$?

Comment: Do you mean any open interval in $R$ is uncountable?

Comment: Thanks for removing the $\cap$ in front of the set.  Also, how is writing $\mathscr{F}$ explicitly as a set helpful in proving the claim? $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ can be finite, countable, or have finite or countable complements.  Also $\emptyset \in \mathscr{F}$.

Comment: Given this definition, why can't intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ (aside from the whole real line itself) be in $\mathscr{F}$?  No interval is countable nor does any interval have a countable complement.

Comment: I have trouble when I tried to prove that $\mathscr{F}$ is closed under countable unions, that part of $A_{n}$'s are countable sets, and the other of $A_{n}$'s are uncountable sets.

Comment: @user81235 If at least one of the $A_n$ has an at-most-countable complement that means the union itself has an at-most-countable complement, since any countable $A_i, \; i \neq n$ can only cover at most a countable number of points that $A_n$ doesn't.

Comment: I only know that nonempty open interval is uncountable. But I am not sure whether the complement of no empty open interval is uncountable.

Comment: @user81235 Why?  The complement of any interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is just another interval.  Therefore every interval of $\mathbb{R}$ (aside $\mathbb{R}$ itself) has an uncountable complement.  Therefore no open interval is either countable or has at-most-countable complement.